# Visio 2010: can one change predefined shapes into others?

Tags: visio

I am drawing a visio diagram and would like to change (i.e. reduce) the radius of the corners of some of my rounded boxes. 
I searched the program's help and googled for >1/2 hour but can't find any hint on how to achieve this - at least none that works.

The context dialog shows a Rounded corner section (Right-click => Format => Line), but any change done there has no effect whatsoever. Does one maybe have to "unprotect" these settings? If so: how?

Any expert who knows how to change the corners' radius?

Later Edit: I just realized: I had used a flow chart symbol "Rounded Process" instead of a plain vanilla rounded box to draw this diagram. That's why I can't change these corners!
Is there an elegant way to globally change a shape into another type, i.e. these flowchart shapes into plain vanilla boxes? Ideally while keeping the associated text?

M.

Comment: This isn't the right forum for this question.  Possibly, "superuser" forum is better suited for it.

Answer (score 1):

not without coding.
However, I'm pretty sure that Sandrilla has a ready to use tool.
It's available for reasonable money. http://www.sandrila.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own shape in such situation, you can can create your own Stencil and then add the your predefined shapes into it. To add the predefined shapes into the stencil just follow the procedure

1. Select the shape from an existing Stencil and Right click on it
2. From the Menu select 'Add to My Shapes'
3. Create New stencil or add it to an existing Stencil.

Now you can edit the master shape but before that you have to put the Stencil in the Edit mode.
Right click on the newly added shape in the Stencil and click 'Edit Master' -> 'Edit Master Shape'

You can now modify the Shape as per your need , for ex. If you want to edit the Corner of the Shape then you right click on the Shape in the Master and then Select 'Format' - > 'Line'  and then select type of corner from the 'Round corner' section.